# how can i get the reference of parent version in child pom?

Tags: maven, maven-3

HI following is my parent pom id's

```
<groupId>com.edb.fs.enterprise.ipr</groupId>
    <artifactId>ipr-system</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>`
```

and child id are

```
  <parent>
<groupId>com.edb.fs.enterprise.ipr</groupId>
<artifactId>ipr-system</artifactId>
<version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>ipr-config</artifactId>
```

i have around 12 child modules , when it comes to release of project if i want my parent version from 1.0.6-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.8-SNAPSHOT again i have to go to each child modules and need to change to required version . is there any solution that i can change it in parent pom and i can refer the same in all child with out hard coding ??

Comment: Why would you need submodules if they would refer to a hard-coded parent POM version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `maven-release plugin` that will handle deploying version without SNAPSHOT and bumping up release number.

Follow documentation: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin

You can also use `versions-maven-plugin`. Just type:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.8-SNAPSHOT
mvn versions:commit
```

Documentation: http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin